# python: parsing xml file with xmlns without class

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Below is the XML file:

```
<Schedule xmlns="http://xmlns.xyz.com/fal/downtimeschedule/V1.0">
 <Downtime end="20181020000" id="10001197610_20181027000_201810000" mode="cold" start="20181020000"/>
 <PODS>
  <POD DC="US - Washing" deferUpgrade="true" name="ABCD" patching="Production" EndTime="20181028040000">
   <CR id="12345"/>
   <CR id="12346"/>
   <CR id="123"/>
  </POD>
  <POD DC="US - Washing" deferUpgrade="true" name="ABCD-TEST" patching="Production" EndTime="20181028040000">
   <CR id="12345"/>
   <CR id="12346"/>
   <CR id="123"/>
  </POD>
 </PODS>
```

I want to provide output in csv file with column

```
1> POD(name)
2> POD(DC)
3> POD(deferUpgrade)
```

Can someone help here. Is it possible using library xml.etree.ElementTree as I have this in production environment.

Below is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('schedule.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

print root
print root.findall('PODS')
for pods in root.iter('Schedule'):
 for pod in pods.iter('POD'):
    print pod.get('name')
```

output:

```
<Element '{http://xmlns.oracle.com/falcm/flo/downtimeschedule/V1.0}Schedule' at 0x2ae6ed0>
[]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself to solve your task? If so, could you please post the code you're struggling with. We'd love to help, but it would be nice if there were some sign of effort that we could work from rather than us creating things for every single question that pops up on SO :) [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) has documentation on just this, so yes, that's a good start.

Comment: you can use xml.dom and import minidom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def parseXml(filePath):

    xmldoc = minidom.parse(filePath)
    PODs= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("POD")
    name=[]
    DC=[]
    deferUpgrade=[]
    for pod in PODs:
        if pod.hasAttribute("name") and pod.hasAttribute("DC") and pod.hasAttribute("deferUpgrade"):
            name.append(pod.getAttribute("name"))
            DC.append(pod.getAttribute("DC"))
            deferUpgrade.append(pod.getAttribute("deferUpgrade"))
    return(name,DC,deferUpgrade)
```

You can use name,DC,deferUpgrade to make your CSV file